# "This is not a record"-Error when trying to sort a list

Tags: list, sorting, functional-programming, elm

I want to sort my list descended but when I use the keyword .sort I get an error:

> This is not a record, so it has no fields to access!
>
> 106|       { model | teams = List.sort.map (\p -> {p | activated =
>   True}) model.teams, activatedOutput = True} 
>                                ^^^^^^^^^ This `sort` value is a:
>
> ```
> List comparable -> List comparable
> ```
>
> But I need a record with a map field!

This is the line I have modified and with which I want to sort the list.

```
Submit -> 
      { model | teams = List.sort.map (\p -> {p | activated = True}) model.teams, activatedOutput = True}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`.sort` is not a keyword, it is a function inside the `List` module. There are several types of sorting function.

The signature of `sort` is:

```elm
sort : List comparable -> List comparable
```

Which means that the values in the lists themselves have to be `comparable` which has special meaning in Elm. Specifically, only built-in things like numbers and strings are comparable. Custom types are not comparable, and neither are booleans.

It may sound strange to hear that booleans do not fit the `comparable` classification but consider this: What does it mean to ask the question, is `True` greater than or less than `False` in every scenario? Rather, you'll have to come up with your own definition of how to sort your custom object.

And for that, we can use the `List.sortBy` function, which has this signature:

```elm
sortBy : (a -> comparable) -> List a -> List a
```

This can sort a list of anything, as long as you provide a function that defines how to sort the thing.

So if you want those teams where `activated` is `True` to be shown at the top, you can use this for sorting:

```elm
List.sortBy (\x -> if x.activated then 0 else 1) model.teams
```

Whereas if you want teams where `activated` is `False` to be at the top, you can use this:

```elm
List.sortBy (\x -> if x.activated then 1 else 0) model.teams
```

Comment: and x would be the property I want to have it sorted for